# RadGrid- getting dropdownlist index using javascript

Tags: javascript, telerik, radgrid

I have another issue with using RadGrid control from telerik.

I am trying to get/set the value of a GridDropDowncolumn in RadGrid using javascript **(in edit mode)**. Could anyone suggest the appropriate javascript method to do this?

So I have the following RadGrid GridDropDownColumn:

```
                <telerik:GridDropDownColumn DataField="ProjectileTypeId" HeaderText="Projectile Type"
                 DataSourceID="ProjectileTypesDataSource" 
                 UniqueName="ProjectileType"
                 ListTextField="Name" ListValueField="Id" />
```

Now I am tring to get the current dropdown's selected index in javascript **(during edit mode)**

What I have at the moment is:

```
    var radGrid = $get("RadGrid1");
    var griddropdownlistElement = $telerik.findElement(radGrid, "ProjectileType");
```

However not sure of the appropriate javascript method to set/get the value.

Answer (score 0):

you have to provide a index to each dropdown in the grid and based on that index you can get the selected index, to do this you can see the following example:
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/grid/get-dropdownlist-value-from-rad-grid.aspx

Comment: Not sure if that helps since I am using a GridDropdownColum instead of a Dropdownlist nested in a GridTemplateColumn. Anyway I will see how that goes...